# 15A tandem Square D TYPE TIPO HOM breaker

Tags: electrical

My breaker panel is full and I want to add a sub panel (50ft on the opposite side of the basement). I need to consolidate some 15A breakers to tandem breakers. I cannot find the breaker I need (15A tandem Square D TYPE TIPO HOM), please help.[image]

Comment: Is this what you are looking for:  https://www.homedepot.com/s/hom%2520breakers%2520tandem?NCNI-5

Comment: Does  your panel *support* tandem breakers?  [edit] your post to include a photo of the label.

Comment: We cannot tell from the “dead face” or cover, the only way to know if your panel can support tandems is from the inside label, they make both a 42 and a 42/84  size panel. The straight 42 has a lighter buss and can not support tandems the 42/84 could have a tandem in each of the 42 spaces for a total of 82 circuits.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Unfortunately, "shopping" questions are off-topic here. Please [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Comment: What wire would you recommend using to add a 125A sub panel? I'll be running a 125A breaker. It looks like most forums recommend #2. It also looks like aluminum is much cheaper. Are there pros and cons to aluminum vs. copper?

Comment: Can you post a full photo of the panel please?  This shouldn't be too hard to find...also, are you sticking the subpanel right next to the main panel, or off somewhere else in the house?

Comment: @tom Kelly , 50’ for a large sub aluminum’s the way to go much cheaper and is fine for a feeder. We’re you able to identify if your panel can use tandems? If you pull the dead face there should be a sticker inside if it states 42 / 84 or 2 sets of numbers it can take them. Some panels only allow 1/2 dozen 42 / 48 would be the number in this case.